# PHP: Select and left join large data base

Tags: php, mysql, select, large-data

`Users` table have 870.000 records

And `info` table have 2.750.000 records

I want select from `users` and join to `info`

If I use below code, my page give timeout error

```
"SELECT `user_id`,`info_name`,`info_family` FROM `user` LEFT JOIN `info` ON `info_user`=`user_id`"
```

`user_id` and `info_user` are index

Note: sometimes i want get `info_date`, `info_birthday` and etc. together

Comment: Indexes are useless when you select all the data. This takes time. Do you really need all?

Comment: Add indexes for the columns you use in your `where` clause

Comment: @juergend for make navigation and get number of that i need it

Comment: To get the count - use `count()` and don't select all data

Comment: i use count(`user_id`) but it make timeout again

Comment: Now what is the real query? Also look at the output of `explain select ...`